# Is there a way to achieve task scheduling in flutter for both Android and iOS with flex interval

Tags: android, ios, flutter, scheduled-tasks

Android introduced WorkManager which can be used for periodic requests or called task scheduling with flex intervals. The following figure shows it clearly.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this in flutter for both Android and iOS at once?